# IntelliJ IDEA Puts Checkout Files in Changelist Other Than Default for Perforce

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce

My IDEA is linked to perforce. When I check out files for editing in IDEA, it automatically puts the checked out files into a changelist other than the default one. How can I change the settings so that the checked out files are to be put in default changelist?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA synchronizes the CLs with Perforce. Are your files opened in a non-default CL in Perforce as well?

Comment: @yole: how do choose which CL to open a file in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to change the "Active Changelist" in Idea. Here are the steps:

1. In Idea, open “Change Tool Window” by clicking on Menu “View” -> “Tool Windows” -> “Changes"
2. Right click on the “Default” changelist(or any changelist you want to set to active/default) in the Tool Windows and click “Set Active"

Comment: This has changed a little 2015. Now look for View - Tool Windows - Perforce.